# Densities and Cumulative Distribution Functions

Tags: probability, density-function, cumulative-distribution-function

Has anyone seen this notation before? What does it mean?

$\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x) G(x) dx$

$f(x)$ is a density and $G(x)$ is a cumulative distribution function

Comment: Can you tell us a little more? In which context did you see this? is $G(x)$ the cdf corresponding to the density $f(x)$, or is it some other cdf?

Comment: I have something like $f(x)=pr(I'=k, x \leq M'<x+dx)$ and $G(x)=pr(M \leq x)$

Comment: I interpreted $f(x)$ and $G(x)$ as density and cdf. I am not sure if I am correct. What does it mean? Any reference is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are independent continuous random variables with pdfs $f$ and $g$ respectively, and that
$G$ is the CDF of $Y$. Suppose also that $X \geq 0$.

Then,
\begin{align}
P\{Y \leq X\} & = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^x f(x)g(y)\,
\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) \left[\int_{-\infty}^x g(y)\,
\mathrm dy\right]\,\mathrm dx\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) G(x)\,\mathrm dx\\
&= \int_0^\infty f(x) G(x)\,\mathrm dx
&\scriptstyle{\text{since}~ f(x) = 0~\text{when}~ x < 0}
\end{align}
Note that it is not necessary to assume that $Y$ is
positive (having $X \geq 0$ suffices), and that we
get the *expected* value of $P\{Y \leq X\}$
(as in kjetil b halvorsen's answer) only in the sense that $P\{Y \leq X\}$ is a constant whose
expected value is just that constant.

If $X$ can take on both positive and negative values, then
$$\int_0^\infty f(x) G(x)\,\mathrm dx 
= P\left(\{Y \leq X\}\cap \{X \geq 0\}\right).$$

Answer (score 1):

I assume both the density $f(x)$ and the cdf $G(x)$ refers to random variables on the interval $(0, \infty)$. Let $X$ be a random variable with the density $f$ and $Y$ be a random variable with the cdf $G $. Then 
$$ \DeclareMathOperator{\E}{\mathbb{E}}  \DeclareMathOperator{\P}{\mathbb{P}}
  \int_0^\infty f(x) G(x) \; dx = \E_X G(X) = \E_X \P (Y \le X)
$$
If you could tell us some more about the context where you saw this, we might tell you why it could be useful.

Comment: Does your comment apply in the situation where $f(x)dx=pr(I′=k,x \leq M′<x+dx)$ and $G(x)=pr(M \leq x)$?

Comment: I show this in the book an introduction to probability and applications. I do not have anything more.